# Java Log formatter is reset

Tags: java, mysql, logging

I initialize the logger like this:

```
public static void init() {
   ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
   handler.setFormatter(new LogFormatter());
   Logger.getLogger(TrackerConfig.LOGGER_NAME).setUseParentHandlers(false);
   Logger.getLogger(TrackerConfig.LOGGER_NAME).addHandler(handler);
}
```

The LogFormatter's format function:

```
@Override
public String format(LogRecord record) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   sb.append(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z").format(new Date(record.getMillis())))
   .append(" ")
   .append(record.getLevel().getLocalizedName()).append(": ")
   .append(formatMessage(record)).append(LINE_SEPARATOR);

   return sb.toString();
}
```

To use the Log I use the following method:

```
private static void log(Level level, String message) {
   Logger.getLogger(TrackerConfig.LOGGER_NAME).log(level, message);
   if (level.intValue() >= TrackerConfig.DB_LOGGER_LEVEL.intValue()) {
      DBLog.getInstance().log(level, message);
   }
}
```

The DBLog.log method:

```
public void log(Level level, String message) {
   try {
      this.logBatch.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));
      this.logBatch.setString(2, level.getName());
      this.logBatch.setString(3, message);
      this.logBatch.addBatch();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Log.logError("SQL error: " + ex.getMessage()); // if this happens the code will exit anyways so it will not cause a loop
   }
}
```

Now a normal Log output looks like that:

> 2013-04-20 18:00:59 +0200 INFO: Starting up Tracker

It works for some time but the LogFormatter seems to be reset for whatever reason.

Sometimes only one Log entry is displayed correctly and after that the Log entries are displayed like:

> Apr 20, 2013 6:01:01 PM package.util.Log log INFO:
>
> Loaded 33266 database entries.

again.

What I tried:

For debugging purposes I added a thread that outputs the memory usage of the jvm every x seconds.
The output worked with the right Log Format until the reserved memory value changed (the free memory value change did not reset the log format) like this:

> 2013-04-20 18:16:24 +0200 WARNING: Memory usage: 23 / 74 / 227 MiB
>
> 2013-04-20 18:16:25 +0200 WARNING: Memory usage: 20 / 74 / 227 MiB
>
> 2013-04-20 18:16:26 +0200 WARNING: Memory usage: 18 / 74 / 227 MiB
>
> Apr 20, 2013 6:16:27 PM package.util.Log log WARNING:
>
> Memory usage: 69 / 96 / 227 MiB
>
> Apr 20, 2013 6:16:27 PM package.util.Log log INFO:
>
> Scheduler running
>
> Apr 20, 2013 6:16:27 PM package.Log log WARNING:
>
> Memory usage: 67 / 96 / 227 MiB

Also note that the log level seems to be reset from warning to info here.

Where the problem seems to be:

When I comment out the database log function like this:

```
private static void log(Level level, String message) {
   Logger.getLogger(TrackerConfig.LOGGER_NAME).log(level, message);
   if (level.intValue() >= TrackerConfig.DB_LOGGER_LEVEL.intValue()) {
      // DBLog.getInstance().log(level, message);
   }
}
```

the log is formatted properly.

Any ideas what could be wrong with the DBLog's log function or why the log suddenly resets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not really call this a solution but it works now.
The cause seemed to be the memory calculation itself.
Even if I just calculated it without logging it, the log format was reset.
I have no idea why it worked when I just commented out the DBLog usage.

```
int mb = 1024 * 1024;
long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / mb;
long reservedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / mb;
long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / mb;
String memoryUsage = "Memory usage: " + freeMemory + " / " + reservedMemory + " / " + maxMemory + " MiB";
```

This is the code I used. As soon as I commented it out the log format did not reset anymore and now everything works as expected.